# Move an asset to another volume with volume specific OptimizedImages Field and on the entry a volume restricted Asset Field

Tags: craft3, assets, plugin-imageoptimize

I have three volumes: content, hero and overview.
Each volume has his specific OptimizedImages Field(s).
Asset Fields are restricted to its specific source volume.

For example: A Super Table Field named hero that contains an Asset Field, which is restricted to the hero source volume.

If an asset is set as a hero image and the client would move the asset in the asset manager to a different volume, two problems appear.

1. On the entry, the image is set as hero image although the field doesn't allow an asset from an other source.
2. In the template you can't call the hero OptimizedImages Field on the asset.

Even if you provide multiple conditionals in the template and some kind of fallback image, the client still sees the image set in the Craft CMS backend.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem without putting everything in one volume?

Comment: You could add the OptimizedImages field to each asset volume? But it sounds like the larger issue is you don't want the client to be able to move images from one asset volume to another?

Comment: @andrew.welch Well it would be great if the client could move assets between volumes but it doesn't seem possible in Craft CMS due to the asset field source restriction is not compatible with the multiple volumes feature. Adding a permission for moving assets between volumes would indeed be a solution.